# How to convert a mesh to a STEP file

Tags: mesh, step

I want to convert a mesh (*.obj, *.stl) to a step file. Is this possible?
I converted each triangle to a face and the result step file was too large to use. Is there any method to convert mesh triangles to NURBS?

Comment: STEP files define a geometry, not a mesh, so conversion doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Are you referring to mesh in the context of Blender?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. There is no way to convert triangles to NURBS surfaces for a number of reasons. Some software [tools](https://www.3dsystems.com/software/geomagic-design-x), with a good amount of manual work, can accomplish this task but it is not a file conversion operation as you requested.